# Powershell not running on cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm trying to run the following command but when I do it the CMD windows closes without the command being executed

the command is

```
cmd.exe /c powershell.exe (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(https://site,'%temp%\file.txt');Start-Process '%temp%\file.txt'
```

Comment: Why are you opening another cmd.exe window, when you are already running your command from one? I would offer this alternative: `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://domain.name/file.name', '%temp%\file.txt'); Start-Process -FilePath '%temp%\file.txt'"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `cmd` here at all¹. You can spawn a process without a shell just as well. Furthermore, it's usually a good idea to quote arguments to avoid surprises with argument parsing (`cmd` for example has its own meaning for parentheses, which may well interfere here).

powershell -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://site',$Env:Temp + '\file.txt');Invoke-Item $Env:Temp\file.txt"

I've also added quotes around the URL you want to download, since that wouldn't otherwise work, either. And since `cmd` is no longer around, environment variables can be expanded by PowerShell as well, with a different syntax.

`Start-Process` also is for starting processes and `Invoke-Item` is closer to what you actually want, although I'm sure with `ShellExecute` behavior, `Start-Process` could launch Notepad with a text file as well if desired.

---

¹ If in doubt, it's always a good idea to reduce the number of parts, processes and different wrapped concepts needed. Same reason why you don't use `Invoke-Expression` in PowerShell to run other programs: Unnecessary, and complicates everything just further by introducing another layer of parsing and interpretation.